# html5 audio player is not working for internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html5-audio

I am using html5 audio but this is not working for internet explorer.

```
<audio id="beep-voice" controls autoplay style="opacity:0"></audio>
```

Please suggest me solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The audio-tag is supported in IE9+. See this site for more information:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

You aren't adding any audio. Try the code below and change the source:

```
<audio id="beep-voice" controls autoplay style="opacity:0">
    <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```